# Regex not matching branch name

Tags: regex, bash, branch, circleci

I have a simple branch to match during circleci build, but for some reason it just won't match

```sh
echo $CIRCLE_BRANCH #this variable is "release-0.0.2"

if [[ $CIRCLE_BRANCH =~ ^release-\d+\.\d+\.\d+ ]]; then
    echo "release branch"
elif [[ $CIRCLE_BRANCH == master ]]; then
    echo "master branch"
fi

# Output
# release-0.0.2
```

I expect the `echo "release branch"` to run, but `^release-\d+\.\d+\.\d+` doesn't seem to match `release-v0.0.2`.

I have tested the regex in an online regex tool and it seems to be correct.

I also tried putting quotes and "/"s around the regex but still no luck

Comment: Do you have "release-0.0.2" or "release-v0.0.2" ? Notice the difference of "v".

Comment: Replace `\d+` with `[[:digit:]]+`, since `\d` is  a PCRE extension; they are not present in the ERE (Posix Extended Regular Expression)  supported by bash